# How closely related are Teorema (1968), Down and Out in Beverly Hills (1986) and Visitor Q (2001)?

Tags: reference, teorema, down-and-out-in-beverly-hills, visitor-q

There are obvious strong parallels but I haven't see any interviews with Mazursky or Miike discussing the Pasolini film.

The core relationship is that all three films involve a mysterious visitor who enters the life of a dysfunctional family and repairs the familial bonds. Thus, all three films share the same basic plot.

Comment: I think it's a fairly common trope in fiction. Also note that _Down and Out in Beverly Hills_ is a remake of a [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudu_Saved_from_Drowning) that predates _Teorema_.

Comment: @Chanadler Bong  Nice. I was unaware of the Renoir!